# O que eu preciso é pegar a chave primaria da tabela Telefone e inserir na FK da tabela Cliente. Como faço?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Cliente (
    id_Cliente INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    nome_Cliente VARCHAR(50),
    fk_ID_Telefone INTEGER
)

CREATE TABLE Telefone (
    id_Telefone INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    fone_Telefone VARCHAR(11)
)
```

Comment: quando for fazer um pergunta veja como formata-la para ficar mais organizado.

Comment: Como dito na resposta você pode fazer um `insert` com `select` mas para isso você deverá especificar a qual cliente pertence aquele telefone. Não sei se é realmente isso que você quer. Tente explicar novamente o que você precisa e demostrar através de exemplos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fazendo um `INSERT` com `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Cliente (fk_ID_Telefone) SELECT id_Telefone FROM Telefone
```

Mas se for um `UPDATE` com `SELECT`:

```
UPDATE Cliente a 
JOIN Telefone b  
SET a.fk_ID_telefone=b.id_Telefone
```

> [Referência do **INSERT com SELECT**](http://codare.aurelio.net/2008/05/17/mysql-insert-com-select-na-mesma-query/)
>
> [Referência do **UPDATE com SELECT**](https://www.gigasystems.com.br/artigo/65/update-a-partir-de-um-select-join)